# Kivy Popup Appearing after function is run instead of before

Tags: python, kivy

I want to display a popup or modal that says something along the lines of 'please be patient while processing' while the application is performing a function in the background. However the popup appears after the background function has already happened. Below is an example of code that produces this problem.

```
import os
import time

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button, Label


class Poppy(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Poppy, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.content = Label(text='working')
        self.open()
        print("Working...")

class TApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text="Click to run", on_press=self.modal_test)

    def modal_test(self, event):
        p = Poppy(size_hint=(0.5, 0.5))
        self.printer()

    def printer(self):
        print('Popup works')
        time.sleep(5)

TApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not execute a time-consuming task on the same GUI thread as it blocks the eventloop causing the GUI to not run correctly. In these cases you must run it in a new thread.

```
import threading
# ...
class TApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text="Click to run", on_press=self.modal_test)

    def modal_test(self, event):
        p = Poppy(size_hint=(0.5, 0.5))
        threading.Thread(target=self.printer, daemon=True).start()

    def printer(self):
        print('before: Popup works')
        time.sleep(5)
        print('after: Popup works')
# ...
```

It is also advisable to check [Working with Python threads inside a Kivy application](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Working-with-Python-threads-inside-a-Kivy-application)

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly and the linked information was also very helpful.